# cordova not updating to latest version

Tags: cordova

I am trying to update my cordova CLI to 6, I ran commands like

```
sudo npm install -g cordova
sudo npm install -g cordova@latest
```

but after these commands are completed successully and then I check the version then I see the same version that was there before that is 5.1.1 by running the following

```
cordova -v
```

**Edited**

Got it working, had to remove the /usr/bin/cordova and symlink the npm version to point to /usr/bin/cordova

Comment: r u installing npm to different location?

Comment: @MyMasterPeice npm root is /home/javadev1/.node/lib/node_modules and my cordova is installed in /usr/bin/cordova

Comment: try installing version directly `npm install cordova@6.2.0`

Comment: or direct download from here ->https://www.versioneye.com/nodejs/cordova/6.2.0

Comment: @MyMasterPeice I removed the /usr/bin/cordova manually and I do have the cordova but is not available to me directly, I have to do /home/javadev1/.node/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova -v in order to see the latest version, will symlink the same with /usr/bin

Answer (score 1):

First uninstall cordova using following command

```
 sudo npm uninstall -g cordova
```

Then clear npm cache

```
sudo npm cache clean
```

And install cordova again

```
sudo npm install -g cordova
```

Comment: running the mentioned commands still gives the same version, after uninstalling cordova too I was able to see cordova -v as 5.1.1

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I am using Windows 7 and upgraded to node 6.
It turns out npm earlier was storing global packages in C:\User\\AppData\roaming folder.

Upgraded packages were stored in C:\ProgramFiles\NodeJs\Packages.
I had to removev C:\User..\AppData\Roaming package from the environment path, to get to upgraded cordova files